# Windows phone- Virtual machine issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am getting the following error when trying to open a windows phone application:

> Virtual Machine Management Service isn't running
>
> The windows Phone Emulator can't start without this Hyper-V service

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of WP are you developing for? **WP 8** requires **Hyper-V** to be enabled and installed. You can enable **Hyper - V** in you **BIOS**, if your processor supports it. Once you enable it in **BIOS**, you also have to enable it in **Programs** and **Settings** in the **control panel**.

Here's an MSDN reference on the topic of **Hyper-V and WP8**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx